# Cómo conectar con una BD de MS Access en remoto con PHP

Tags: php, ms-access

¿Qué parámetros he de meter para conectar con una BBDD de MS Access en remoto?
Actualmente meto el siguiente código:

```
$conMSAccess=odbc_connect("dsn", "usuario", "password");
```

El problema es que se ve que conecta en local, pero la BBDD está en remoto con una determinada IP. Me da el siguiente fallo

> odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][Administrador de controladores ODBC] No se encuentra el nombre del origen de datos y no se especific� ning�n controlador predeterminado".

Me estoy conectando desde PHP.

He buscado en la sintaxis pero no he encontrado nada. ¿Alguna idea? Gracias.

Comment: Según lo indicado en el [Manual de PHP (ver **Ejemplo 1** del mismo)](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.odbc-connect.php), tienes que pasar los parámetros así: **`$conMSAccess = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$mdbFilename", $user, $password);`** Revisa allí mismo a qué corresponde cada variable para que las definas adecuadamente.

Comment: ODBC no permite conexiones vía TCP. Una opción es generando una carpeta compartida a donde tengas la base y accediendo al share como `\\11.2.333.4\share\bd.mdb`, siempre y cuando el usuario que corre el servidor (IIS/Apache) tenga permiso para acceder.

Comment: ¿La variable Dbq=$mdbFilename sería el nombre del archivo no? En mi caso, que es una tabla en el servidor, con un nombre y una dirección IP... ¿qué sería? Es que sospecho que no se puede conectar con lo que te da la documentación de PHP a un MS Access alojado en un servidor...